# Center bar buttons in toolbar in Xcode

Tags: ios, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I have two buttons inside of a toolbar that is positioned at the bottom of the screen. I would like to center those buttons within the toolbar. Everything I have found is focused on centering buttons within a nav bar and I am unsure of how to approach this issue. What am I missing?

[image]

This is the UI I am attempting to emulate:

[image]

Comment: You can use the flexible width or fixed width toolbar items (You can drag and drop it in your toolbar) and adjust based on your requirement

Comment: When I attempt to drag the item, the button snaps to the available leftmost space within the toolbar.

Comment: Add one flexible space to the left and another one to right

Comment: Oh god, that was easy. That you for spelling it out for me.

Comment: Happy to hear that it worked for you :) Happy Coding !!!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Adding a flexible space to the left and right of the buttons centered the buttons inside of the toolbar. Thanks to Midhun MP for the tip.

Comment: flexible spacing works!. I remember using similar technique in the web world.

Answer (score 0):

Thks @Andrew, it works 
but for someone who wants it from code here is the example in Swift 5.0

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        navigationController?.setToolbarHidden(false, animated: true)
        let spaceItemLeft = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)
        let nextItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "NEXT", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(nextTapped))
        let spaceItemRight = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: self, action: nil)
        toolbarItems = [spaceItemLeft, nextItem, spaceItemRight]
    }

    @objc func nextTapped() {
        print("NEXT Tapped")
    }
```